# Adding values to some divs withing a wrapped set with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am so bad with jquery I should ask for forgiveness :)

I have a div element similar to this:

```
<div id="MyDiv"><span id="Title"></span><div id="Text"></div></div>
```

I find it with the proper selector:

```
var myDiv = $("#MyDiv")
```

Now that I have this wrapped set I would like to find the "Title" span and "Text" div to put some text in each WITHOUT modifying the "MyDiv" div in the page so I can do something like the following:

```
CallMyFunction(myDiv);
```

How do I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How many elements have an `id` of `Title`?

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Fair question James. I am very new to jquery so I am reading and trying to find out how I could do this. My problem is that I need to deliver my story ASAP so I'm a little time pressured. :(

Comment: @Blender: There is and always will be only one element of each.

Comment: Sergio, I understand time pressure, but instead of making a new question for this, you could have googled or searched stackoverflow for "how to add text to a div jquery" or something similar and immediately gotten a result.

Comment: did you even try to google before posting it here?

Comment: @Colleen: I am always very diligent about that. The answers I found are not exactly what I want, at least from my understanding of jquery. I DO NOT want to modify the elements ON THE PAGE, I want to get the wrapped set in memory and modify it there and I haven't found a way of doing it. I've spend all afternoon googling. Seems a little unfair to be downvoted :(

Comment: Then you need to modify your question, because that isn't AT ALL how your question is phrased, as is evidenced by everyone suggesting you use .text()

Comment: And if you want to get it in memory and modify it there, you can't do that with javascript. Javascript is entirely client side.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the text, modify it, and send it as a string? I'm trying to reconcile the two things you've said and am now extra unclear about what you want.

Comment: @Colleen: I've clarified the question to be more precise in what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sounds like what you want to do is, in your function call, assign a clone of the div you want to a variable, edit it, and then get its html and call the other function with it, like

```
function dosomething(myDiv){
    var texttodosomethingwith = getmodifiedhtml(myDiv);
    //do something with texttodosomethingwith
}

function getmodifiedhtml(element){
    var cloneddiv = element.clone();
    var innerspan = cloneddiv.children('span')[0];
    $(innerspan).text(sometext);
    var innerdiv = cloneddiv.children('div')[0];
    $(innerdiv).text(someothertext);
    return cloneddiv.html();
}
```

does that sound like what you want? Cloning will copy the div without appending it to the page, so you get the same structure and ids while leaving the page intact.

note that you will want to call dosomething with the jquery selection of your element, like dosomething($("#mydiv"));

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ID's you can access them directly:

```
$("#Title").text("My title text");
$("#Text").text("My text");
```

And to get the html:

```
var myHTML = $("#MyDiv").html();
```

If you have more than one element with ID of `Title` or `Text`, **you do not have valid HTML**.

If so, you need to change them to classes, then you would use `.find()`:

```
$("#MyDiv").find(".Title").text("My title text");
$("#MyDiv").find(".Text").text("My text");
```

Answer (score 0):

To add some text to span `#Title`,

```
 $('#Title').text('Some Text'); 
 //Use .html inplace of .text incase if you are adding html content
```

Likewise inside the div `#Text`,

```
 $('#Text').text('Some More Text'); 
 //Use .html inplace of .text incase if you are adding html content
```

And Now to send the whole content use `.html()` function like below,

```
var myDivContent = $("#MyDiv").html();
```